# firebase db changes websocket?

Tags: websocket, firebase

I am looking for a good way to monitor changes on firebase to update my sql data tables accordingly.

I do not use nodejs (not yet), can I listen to firebase changes using websockets? This particular code base is coldfusion.

Thank You!

Comment: So you would like to connect through a websocket to Firebase so that it can push notifications to you, right?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yes! I want to listen for firebase db changes to update our on-premises tables.

Comment: There's `Firebase.on` (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) which does that.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv will this work even if I dont have any pages open? The reason I am interested in websockets is that I can run websockets in the background.

Comment: If you can run JS in the background then yes, it will work but it's really up to the Firebase API implementation if it uses websockets or something else.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Thank you - looks like we need nodejs in that case.

Comment: 2 years later cloud functions can be triggered from db changes :)

Answer (score 3):

You should check out Firebase's [REST Streaming API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) - it's not websockets specifically, but you can listen to changes on a Firebase database location using Server-Sent Events ([SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)) over a long-lived HTTP connection

Comment: Thank You! this is probably what we will do on pages that the user is viewing to see real-time updates from mobile clients.